# What actually processes a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

A Dockerfile defines the process for building a Docker image. What actually processes the Dockerfile? I'm assuming it's a component that belongs to Docker that first begins the Dockerfile processing? If so, what component is that, and is it the only component that handles the main processing of the Dockerfile?

Comment: as a user, do you need know that? and docker is open source, just check the go source?

Answer (score 0):

When you issue the command:

```
docker image build --tag xxxx/yyyy:1.0.0 .
```

It's this Docker command line `build` sub-command which reads and processes the Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks Roslan. I upvoted as this is a good hint for where to start looking in the sourcecode, (as suggested by Lei Yang). I wonder if this is better as a comment though, as it's a hint as to where to start looking, rather than a definitive answer

Comment: I thought about that but decided on an answer because it is a straight-up answer to the question. :)